# Adding a triangle in css under another element

Tags: html, css

I have been trying hard without success to add a little triangle under my square to act as a pointer like this:

[image: example of what I mean]

My code by itself works, but whenever I try to add css to make this triangle nothing will appear. I think it has to do with before-after functions, but I'm not really getting it. Anyone can help me with that?

```html
<div id="slider_outer1">
<div class="slider_segment"><img src="myurl.com" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;"></div>
<div id="slider_marker1"></div>
</div>
<style>    
    .container {width:400px;}
    
    #slider_outer1 {width: 98%;border: 5px solid #8f89ff; position: relative;display: inline-block; border-radius: 5px;}
    
    .slider_segment {width: 100%; float: left; display: inline;}
    
#slider_marker1 {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #574fff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 5%;
    top: 120px;
    left: 57.25%;
    text-align: center;
    Margin-left: -10%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
    
div#slider_marker1:after {
    content: "5";
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
        
</style>
```

edit: code of the triangle

```html
<div class="triangle-down"></div>
<style>
.triangle-down {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 15px solid transparent;
 border-right: 15px solid transparent;
 border-top: 20px solid #555;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I use this site as reference, [link](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/), then I will just edit the generated triangle as per my requirement. But @MARyan87 answer works perfectly! Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in CSS triangles are made using borders, not before and after pseudo elements.  To create a downward pointing triangle, you would create a top border of `n` number of pixels, and left and right borders of ***half*** that width and also transparent.

**Example:**

```
    <div id="slider_outer1">
<div class="slider_segment"><img src="myurl.png" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;"></div>
<div id="slider_marker1"><div id='triangle-down'></div></div>


</div>
<style>    
    .container {width:400px;}

    #slider_outer1 {width: 98%;border: 5px solid #8f89ff; position: relative;display: inline-block; border-radius: 5px;}

    .slider_segment {width: 100%; float: left; display: inline;}

#slider_marker1 {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #574fff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 5%;
    top: 120px;
    left: 57.25%;
    text-align: center;
    Margin-left: -10%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#triangle-down {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid blue;
}

div#slider_marker1:after {
    content: "5";
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

</style>
```

See my codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvXOab

Comment: Borders and pseudo elements are not mutually exclusive things. A pseudo element can have a border and be easily made into a triangle shape, using the same CSS approach as any other element. The only difference would be the requirement for setting content: "";

Answer (score 0):

You could add another div for the triangle like

```
<div id='triangle'></div>
```

Css For the triangle...

```
#triangle{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 40px solid transparent;
    border-right: 40px solid transparent;
    border-top: 80px solid blue;
}
```

However I feel that your problem is not that it just isnt appearing its that the positioning is messed up so its 'hidden' behind the sliders

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to make. This should add a triangle above the marker. This solution should allow you to also remove anything related to `triangle-down` as it only requires the `slider_marker1` div

```
#slider_marker1::before {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid green;
    z-index: 100;
}
```